# Angular and TypeScript: instantiating an instance of a class from a JSON object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface to represent the response from my Web API:

```
interface Person {
  dateofbirth: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}
```

But I don't want to deal with a string representation of a date-time. Instead, I want to deal with a `MomentJS` object. So I create a class for a view model that has a `MomentJS` property. When constructing it, I convert the string to a `MomentJS` object:

```
class PersonViewModel {
      dateofbirth: Moment.moment;
      firstname: string;
      lastname: string;

      constructor(dateofbirth: string, firstname: string, lastname: string) {
        this.dateofbirth = moment.utc(dateofbirth);
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
      }
}
```

But, if the response from the Web API contains more than 10 fields (which is usually the case), I find myself doing a lot of manual work. I tried third-party tools that make it easier to instantiate objects given a JSON object, but I don't want to rely on third-party tools for such a critical part of my application.

My question is - is there any native TypeScript feature that could simplify this process? Or should I take an entirely different approach?

Comment: Maybe one solution could be to use a setter and/or a getter for `dateofbirth` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the moment instance is not just created by `new Moment`, but via a static moment function. Other classes or object might get instantiated via `new SomeClass()`. So a generic approach to this problem is basically impossible.

Also this would mean to differentiate between primitives and classes/objects. But in Typescript you can also create union types like `string | SomeClass`. In runtime it would be a whole lot of work to check the specific type of each parameter given.